# Generating link to google maps based on polygon coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a bunch of coordinates for a number of polygons which I draw on my embedded google map. Thing is I would like to create a shareable link to google maps site where I could view created polygons based on that data.

I have checked https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide and there is lots of information how to draw routes and markers but I cannot find anything how to draw my polygons similarly to what you can achieve by marking your data on your Maps or importing coords data into [My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1W-H3eCvttkxK2MvHeneBdmAebT4&ll=36.662905875346055%2C-2.388177109374965&z=7)